# How can I resolve communication issues between a websocket server and client deployed on Docker using the socketio library and Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker-compose, socket.io, dockerfile

First of all i'm a very begginer with docker and socket.io.

I want to deploy on docker with a docker-compose file, a websocket server with [socketio library](https://pypi.org/project/python-socketio/), and a client that sends message to the server with socketio library too.

My issue is even with putting the same network and specify  the host of the server as '0.0.0.0' it seem that the client can't communicate with the server, I specify the port like this `app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')`

I don't know if it's important but I use flask to run my socketio app

```
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode='threading', cors_allowed_origins='*')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio, app.wsgi_app)
```

My docker compose :

```
  client-liveserver:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: live-server-client
    build:
      context: ./docker/docker_python
    volumes:
      - ./docker/docker_python/python:${WEB_ROOT}
    command:  python3 app/client.py
    networks:
      - socket-network

  liveserver:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: live-server-python
    build:
      context: ./docker/docker_python
    volumes:
      - ./docker/docker_python/python:${WEB_ROOT}
    depends_on:
      - client-liveserver
    command:  python3 app/webserver.py
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - socket-network
```

The Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.9.2-alpine3.13


RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    pip install --no-cache-dir \
    requests \
    flask \
    kafka-python \
    python-socketio 
    
COPY ./python /app
```